# Problem with Office 2007 Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

I can't open Outlook, I can't open default email folder and I can't find data files for receiving and sending files.

When I go to control panel mail and try to add one there is error:

> This service is not installed.

Can anyone suggest anything to me?

Answer (score 0):

Try the repair installation feature of Office 2007. Just start the normal setup and select repair installation. It´s the same way like installing additional office features/programs.